# how do you create a filter search in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i like the editable filter search list in w3shools.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp.

It is using this below javascript code to do the filtering.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

I need a modification somewhere by SO community so that when the search box has nothing written the returned filtered items is none. In the above code when nothing is written the results is to show all items in the list.

I am not that good with javascript so someone here may be able to re-code this for me. I am thinking the change should should happen in line 11 **for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++)**.

Comment: Probably due to asking for someone else to do it. You'll get better reception if you show what you've tried in a reproducible example, and what issues you're having with your code.

Comment: Why don't you check if your filter input has something you can use before you do anything else?

Comment: I gave you the solution through my question, but you seem to focus more on those minus two point people gave you because you didn't follow the SO guidelines. You can continue doing that, or convert what I told you into code and be done with all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First hide all in CSS `#myUL li {display: none; }`
2. On input show all first so search can search text (created `showALL()` function call it on input), this needs to be done because search does not work on display none elements.
3. React only if input is not empty - added to filter `if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && input.value != "") {`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  
  showALL() // on input show all

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && input.value != "") { 
    // react only if input is not empty with && input.value != ""
      li[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

// showALL() function you called on input
const showALL = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li')].forEach(
    li => {
      li.style.display = "block";
    }
  )
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myUL {
  /* Remove default list styling */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a border to all links */
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  /* Grey background color */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add some padding */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove default text underline */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase the font-size */
  color: black;
  /* Add a black text color */
  display: block;
  /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
  /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}


/* First hide all */
#myUL li {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow. thank you so much. the answer lies in css file and in a way i still could not have figured it out. wish i could up vote you more times.

Comment: @webzy Np, just consider marking it as accepted anwser on check-mark if all is good. Also I changed selector in showAll function to be more specific so you don't show all other li's on page if there is more hidden.

Comment: that is so great. My project is back to work! But of course i do not understand the solution.